# Disable autocomplete in IronPython REPL

Tags: ironpython

I am using an application called 'Triangle Microworks Communication Protocol Test Harness' that has the IronPython interpreter/shell/REPL embedded into it.  (Not sure what the exact correct term is in the previous sentence.)

An autocomplete box keeps appearing frequently.  I would like to turn it off.  Is this possible within the IronPython session?

Comment: Which tool? The console that comes with IronPython only does autocompletion on tabs - there's no popup box.

Comment: It is called [Triangle Microworks Communication Protocol Test Harness](https://www.trianglemicroworks.com/products/downloads)

Comment: @JeffHardy, is there a way to query the autocompletion list perhaps?  Any way to turn off autocompletion on tabs?

Comment: No, the list is not exposed (although that's an interesting idea for embedding apps). For ipy.exe, you can run it with `-X:BasicConsole` to disable tab completion.